# Java classpath, jar file with no .jar extension in Weblogic over Unix

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, load, classpath, java-ee-5

If I place a file called libA.jar in a classpath folder, and rename the old one to:

libA.jar.old

Will the classloader load the classes?

I'm using weblogic over Solaris 8.

Thank you!

Udo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you're using Java 5 or earlier, you must explicitly name all classes and jar files to be loaded. Obviously, since the old one, libA.jar.old isn't named, it won't be loaded.

It's a bit of a different story if you're using Java 6, since concept of wildcard matching exists there.

Still, non jar files won't be loaded. Info taken from [official site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). Quote:

> Class path entries can contain the
>   basename wildcard character *, which
>   is considered equivalent to specifying
>   a list of all the files in the
>   directory with the extension .jar or
>   .JAR. For example, the class path
>   entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in
>   the directory named foo.
>
> A classpath
>   entry consisting simply of * expands
>   to a list of all the jar files in the
>   current directory. A class path entry
>   that contains * will not match class
>   files. To match both classes and JAR
>   files in a single directory foo, use
>   either foo;foo/* or foo/*;foo. The
>   order chosen determines whether the
>   classes and resources in foo are
>   loaded before JAR files in foo, or
>   vice versa.